# Akka Microkernel on Heroku

Tags: heroku, akka, microkernel

I have an Akka 2.1.0 running on a Microkernel. On my local machine I run `sbt dist` to build the exec and then `cd target/dist` and `bin/akka sample.kernel.hello.HelloKernel`.

Heroku uses an automatic `sbt clean compile stage` command to build a `target/start` script.

Any ideas how I could get around this staging and deploy the Microkernel on Heroku? Maybe some hints about how to change the [heroku-buildpack-scala](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is implicitly about heroku but you may want to try digitalocean.com for hosting that is about 1/8th of the cost of aws and gives you a real vm instead of a drone.

It's much more flexible solution about abuot $5/month for the equivalent of an aws small ($40 a month) and you don't have to worry about anything that is so domain specific.